# form validation with radio buttons and specific errors

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I am trying to make a form validate where there are radio buttons and textarea. I want nothing to be left empty i.e the form should be completely filled. I have done the radio buttons part of validation where if a user does not select a radio button he will get an error for that particular question. you can see the code [here](http://jsbin.com/IxAFoci/1/) for detailed code.

Please help me out. I am not getting error for textarea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you didn't write any validation for 'textarea' block. I have updated it with one textarea... add rest validations.

```
function RadioValidator()
{
    var ShowAlert = '';
    var AllFormElements = window.document.getElementById("FormID").elements;
    for (i = 0; i < AllFormElements.length; i++) 
    {
        if (AllFormElements[i].type == 'radio') 
        {
            var ThisRadio = AllFormElements[i].name;
            var ThisChecked = 'No';
            var AllRadioOptions = document.getElementsByName(ThisRadio);
                        var problem_desc = document.getElementById("problem_desc");

            for (x = 0; x < AllRadioOptions.length; x++)
            {
                 if (AllRadioOptions[x].checked && ThisChecked === 'No' && problem_desc.value === "")
                 {
                     ThisChecked = 'Yes';
                     break;
                 } 
            }

            var AlreadySearched = ShowAlert.indexOf(ThisRadio);
            if (ThisChecked == 'No' && AlreadySearched == -1 && problem_desc.value === "")
            {
            ShowAlert = ShowAlert + ThisRadio + ' option must be selected\n';
            }
        }else if(AllFormElements[i].type =='textarea')
        {
          // add your rest of text area validations here

          var problem_desc_1 = document.getElementById("problem_desc");
          if(problem_desc_1.value === "")
          {

            ShowAlert = ShowAlert + '"Services (Please Specify)" can not be blank. \n';
          }


        }
    }
    if (ShowAlert !== '')
    {
    alert(ShowAlert);
    return false;
    }
    else
    {
    return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to check textarea `AllFormElements[i].value` not element with id = problem_desc.

Answer (score 2):

Just add another check for textarea

```
function RadioValidator() {
    var ShowAlert = '';
    var AllFormElements = window.document.getElementById("FormID").elements;
    for (i = 0; i < AllFormElements.length; i++) {
        var name = AllFormElements[i].name;
        if (AllFormElements[i].type == 'radio') {
           ....       
        } else if (AllFormElements[i].type == 'textarea') {
            if (AllFormElements[i].value == '') {
                ShowAlert += name + ' textarea must be filled\n';
            }
        }
    }
    if (ShowAlert !== '') {
        alert(ShowAlert);
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: when I add this code I only get error to fill the textarea even if I haven't selected a radio button anyways thanks for your help and I think I have got the solution thanks to sameer his code is working.

Comment: sorry I did not knew that +1 added for your code thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a check for `textarea` as well

In your `javascript` check you have only added a condition for type `radio.`
check for `textarea` type as well and add error if the value is blank.